# Validation error of type UnknownType: Unknown type CreateUserInput

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

Using AppSync Query Playground running this query.

```
mutation UserMutation ($input: CreateUserInput!) {
    createUser
      (input: $input) 
      {
          uniqueID
          recordType
          userName
          userEmail
          userEmailVerified
          userCreated
          userLastModified
          userEnabled
          userStatus
          userValidFrom
          userValidTo
      }
    }
```

Query Variables are

```
{
  "input":  
  {
      "uniqueID": "UUID-formatted",
      "recordType": "USER",
      "userName": "username",
      "userEmail": "mailadres",
      "userEmailVerified": true,
      "userCreated": "2020-12-04T22:32:37.000Z",
      "userLastModified": "2020-12-04T22:34:15.000Z",
      "userEnabled": true,
      "userStatus": "CONFIRMED",
      "userValidFrom": "2021-03-12T11:03:37.283Z",
      "userValidTo": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z"
  }
}
```

Creates a record in the DynamoDB table as expected.

Which suggest to me that the model and the resolvers are well defined in AppSync.

Running the exact same code in a NodeJS Express environment creates the above error.

API-key and GraphQL endpoint are correct. Exactly the same method for other entity used and works.

This is the NodeJS code

```
exports.userCreate = (cognitosub, userName, cognitoemail, cognitoemail_verified, cognitoUserCreateDate, cognitoUserLastModifiedDate, cognitoEnabled, cognitoUserStatus, userValidFrom, userValidTo) => {
  const mutateQuery = gql(`
  mutation UserMutation ($input: CreateUserInput!) {
    createUser
      (input: $input) 
      {
          uniqueID
          recordType
          userName
          userEmail
          userEmailVerified
          userCreated
          userLastModified
          userEnabled
          userStatus
          userValidFrom
          userValidTo
      }
    }
  `);
  const mutateVariables = JSON.parse(`{
    "uniqueID" : "${cognitosub}",
    "recordType" : "USER",
    "userName" : "${userName}",
    "userEmail" : "${cognitoemail}",
    "userEmailVerified" : ${cognitoemail_verified},
    "userCreated" : "${cognitoUserCreateDate}",
    "userLastModified" : "${cognitoUserLastModifiedDate}",
    "userEnabled" : ${cognitoEnabled},
    "userStatus" : "${cognitoUserStatus}",
    "userValidFrom" : "${utils.dateConvertToISOString(userValidFrom)}",
    "userValidTo" : "${utils.dateConvertToISOString(userValidTo)}"
  }`)
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    console.debug(`${Date(Date.now())} - utilities.userCreate.mutateVariables`,mutateVariables)
    graphqlClient.mutate({
      mutation: mutateQuery, 
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache', // Mutate suporteert alleen 'no-cache'
      variables: {input: mutateVariables}
    })
      .then((success) => {
        // console.debug(`${Date(Date.now())} - utilities.userCreate.then`,success)
        if (success === null) {reject('userIsNull')}
        else {
          resolve(success.data.createUser.uniqueID)}
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.debug(`${Date(Date.now())} - utilities.userCreate.catch\n`,err)
        reject(err)
      })
  })
```

Exact same code is used for a less complicated object with an UUID, Identification, validFrom en ValidTo date. It works like a charm.

I looked at every error and spelling mistake. The code keeps throwing this two errors.

```
graphQLErrors: [
    {
      path: null,
      locations: [ { line: 1, column: 31, sourceName: null } ],
      message: 'Validation error of type UnknownType: Unknown type CreateUserInput'
    },
    {
      path: null,
      locations: [ { line: 2, column: 3, sourceName: null } ],
      message: "Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'createUser' in type 'Mutation' is undefined @ 'createUser'"
    }
  ]
```

Which are dump of the error-object.

Appolo-client is used top access the DynamoDB. The records created in the AppSync GraphQL playground are perfectly viewable in the DB.

I am out of clues here. Can anyone help?

Comment: why `JSON.parse()`? variables is a simple object you can create simple way

Comment: I am rather new to NodeJS. I quit progamming 15 years ago to start more on the Project and Programme management side of IT-projects. Recently I picked up progamming again to see that lots of things have changed ;-)
Think JSON.parse is needed for the AWSSyncClient

Answer (score 0):

Today I really looked into this problem and decided not to use the AppSync client from AWS anymore (which created some depency build problems with every npm update by the way...)
I choose to go for the Apollo client latest version which doesn't give any npm update issues and is a up-to-date version of the client that AWS uses in the background if I am well informed (read can read fora in a good way ;-))

I had some issues with the authentication on AppSync but managed to get over this.

This code totally fixes ALL previous error (for me)

```
const gql = require("graphql-tag"); 
const ApolloClient = require("@apollo/client").ApolloClient
const ApolloLink = require("@apollo/client").ApolloLink
const InMemoryCache = require("@apollo/client").InMemoryCache;
const createHttpLink = require("@apollo/client").createHttpLink;
const {createAuthLink} = require("aws-appsync-auth-link")
require('cross-fetch/polyfill');

const clientGraphQL = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    createAuthLink({ 
      url: aws_secrets.AWS_DEV_APPSYNC_ENDPOINT, 
      region:aws_secrets.REGION, 
      auth:
        {
          type: "API_KEY",
          apiKey: aws_secrets.AWS_DEV_APPSYNC_API_KEY,
        } 
    }),
    createHttpLink({ 
      uri: aws_secrets.AWS_DEV_APPSYNC_ENDPOINT 
    }),
  ]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

Safe code by hiding all the secrets in a special file.
createAuthLink is the only thing I need from AWSAppSync (IMHO).
I didn't manage to get a proper connection with the CreateAuthLink from the Apollo Client.

Hope this helps some of you...

Comment: Another advantage:
Far better error explanation in the error-object if something goes wrong